# Windows batch file with delayed execution calling SQL Server stored procedure with input parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, batch-file

I have a stored procedure (`zhm.GetBatchCmdList_sp`) with two optional input parameters (`@freq` and `@env`). The stored procedure returns a single column list of SSIS files and stored procedures that I want to execute, one by one.

I've created some test code that simply echoes the stored procedure's result set to console:

```
set freq=D
set env=DEV
set cmd=sqlcmd -S LDNDSM05243\TDS_MAIN2_DEV -d CPRM_3DSTRESS -Q "exec zhm.GetBatchCmdList_sp @freq=$(freq), @freq=$(env)" -h -1
set cmdList=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"%cmd%"`) do (set cmdList=!cmdList! %%i)
for %%v in (%cmdList%) do echo %%v
endlocal
```

but I am having problems with it.

If I remove the input parameters from the above 'set cmd....' line by replacing it with:

```
set cmd=sqlcmd -S LDNDSM05243\TDS_MAIN2_DEV -d CPRM_3DSTRESS -Q "exec zhm.GetBatchCmdList_sp" -h -1
```

then the script runs. However, I want the caller to be able to pass input variables (ie. `%1` and `%2`) to the script (which will pass these to the stored procedure) so that different values for `freq` and `env` can be set at runtime.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I suspect it may have something to do with the combination of stored proc input parameters and enabling delayed expansion.  Of course, I could be wrong, but I've been googling and I can't find any help specific to this combo/question.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit - This is a completely rewritten answer*

Your problem is the `)` in your definition of cmd. You have two sets of quotes, one in your original definition, and then another set in your FOR IN() clause. The net effect is your `)` characters are not quoted, so it terminates the IN() clause prematurely and the statement fails.

As you stated in your comment, changing to `"!cmd!"` solves your problem. But I think you could also have solved it simply by removing the quotes from your IN() clause.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`%cmd%`) do...
```

Comment: "Windows (cmd.exe) uses %var% for immediate expansion at parse time, and !var! for delayed expansion at execution time." That was it. That's what I was doing wrong. I just needed to change the "%cmd%" to "!cmd!" in the first for..in...do statement and it now works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PingPing - I better understand what was wrong now. I've completely re-written the answer.